# Interact with a cute editor using webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, cuteeditor

Does anyone know how I can interact with a cute editor using webdriver. I want to clear the text?

```
 <iframe id="CE_Editor1_ID_Frame" src="cuteeditor_files/template.asp"
 frameborder="0" class="CuteEditorFrame CuteEditorFrame"
 style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
 height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block;"></iframe>
```

the below code won't work?

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
driver.switchTo().activeElement().clear();
```

Comment: What is the `id` of the input area? Try to clear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the Cute Editor's demo at http://cutesoft.net/example/general.aspx, now I understand why you used `driver.switchTo().activeElement()` instead of looking for textarea/input, because the iframe is the 'textarea', and you want to clear everything within the iframe.

I assume yours is similar to the demo

```html
<iframe id="CE_Editor1_ID_Frame" src="cuteeditor_files/template.asp" frameborder="0" class="CuteEditorFrame CuteEditorFrame" style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block;">
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <table>the real stuff in the editor, you want to clear this, right?</table>
            <br>
            <br>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

I don't think Selenium provides anything to delete nodes, but you can achieve this by JavascriptExecutor. **Warning**: untested code, only the logic's here. You need to debug a bit youself.

```java
// first try to avoid switching frames by index, unless you have no other ways.

// if you have only one frame with class name CuteEditorFrame
WebElement editorFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".CuteEditorFrame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(editorFrame);

// if the id 'CE_Editor1_ID_Frame' not dynamic
WebElement editorFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#CE_Editor1_ID_Frame"));
driver.switchTo().frame(editorFrame); // driver.switchTo().frame("CE_Editor1_ID_Frame");

// then remove everything inside the iframe's body
JavascriptExecutor js;
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
}
WebElement editorBody = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerHTML = ''", editorBody);

// alternatively, using sendKeys directly is a better way
WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")); // then you find the body
body.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a"); // send 'ctrl+a' to select all
body.SendKeys("Some text");
```