# How can I find the body of TinyMCE editor using CSS selectors in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, tinymce, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find an element on a page using Selenium. Here is some example content:

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true" dir="ltr"        style="overflow: auto;">
```

Here is how I am trying to select it:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body#tinymce")).sendKeys("Hello, everyone!! Don't worry it is a test letter to check connection!!");
```

I do not get an element returned though.

Comment: Why are you trying to send keys to the `<body>` element? Shouldn't you be typing into a text field?

Comment: Yes you are right, i should type it into a text field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are testing against [TinyMCE editor](http://www.tinymce.com/).

The issues are:

- It's in an iframe, you need to switch into to the iframe first.
- You need to send keys to `<body>` element (not `<input>`) inside that iframe

Here is what to do:

```
// switch to iframe, use locator of your choice, "#editMe_ifr" here as an example
WebElement editorFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#editMe_ifr"));
driver.switchTo().frame(editorFrame);

WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.TagName("body")); // then you find the body
body.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "a"); // send 'ctrl+a' to select all
body.SendKeys("Some text");
```

Further reading:

- [Interact with a cute editor using webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16114854/1177636)
- [Using C# with selenium and cleditor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17054430/1177636).

Answer (score 0):

You can change your HTML to this:

```
<body>
    <input id="tinymce" type="text"/>
</body>
```

And you can change the selector from `body#tinymce` to `#tinymce`. You shouldn't need to specify the tagname when using id because the id should be unique anyway.

Comment: Shouldn't `body#tinymce` mean the `<body>` element with id `tinymce`? Note there's no space in between.